# Visual Studio 2015 update 3 Hangs while typing in long sub

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2015

i have a big problem since the last studio updates wich is getting realy annoying.

I have a sub that contains approximatly 1000 ore more lines of code.
When i try to type something studio will freeze for at least 20 - 30 seconds.

What i tried:
comment out 900 of 1000 lines -> still freezes but only for 5 seconds

delete commented lines -> no freeze

has anyone an idea?

Comment: same problem. really annoying.